# Module with the Main dispatcher is missing

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm, android-mvvm

After researching, I'm still having this issue, but this only happens when my liveData is being populated.

What I'm trying to do is mix LiveData to communicate only from the ViewModel to the UI, and using Coroutines to fetch data from my server.

For now, I just used all the KTX to date to make it more legible

From my UI I just observe data

```
viewModel.data.observe(this,Observer {...})
```

From my ViewModel I'm just launching a suspend function that is executed on IO for network requests, this liveData should return when `emit()` finish fetching the data

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel(private val repo:Repo) {

    val data = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(repo.getUserData2())
    }

}
```

And now from my data source I just fetch some data from Firebase and return it to my `emit()` so I can notify my LiveData about new values.

Here I'm using `kotlinx-coroutines-android` and `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` to use `.await()` on my network request

```
  suspend fun getUserData2(): MutableList<Houses> {

        val houseList = mutableListOf<Houses>()
        val snap = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Houses").get().await()
        for (houses in snap) {
            val name = document.getString("houseName")
            val color = document.getString("houseColor")
            val house = Houses(name!!, color!!)
            listData.add(house)
        }
        return houseList
    }
```

The problem is when it returns to

```
 val data = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(repo.getUserData2())
    }
```

With this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher is
>   missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g.
>   'kotlinx-coroutines-android'
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.missing(MainDispatchers.kt:90)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.isDispatchNeeded(MainDispatchers.kt:71)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedKt.resumeCancellable(Dispatched.kt:420)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:162)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl.emit(CoroutineLiveData.kt:97)
>           at com.gaston.recyclerviewexample.viewmodel.MainViewModel$dataLive$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModel.kt:18)
>           at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)

My dependencies are the follow

```
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-rc02"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in `kotlinx.coroutines`, you can find the issue here:

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1532

You need to downgrade to version `1.3.0`:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"
```

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1532#issuecomment-536299897

Or just wait until version `1.3.3` gets released since it will have the fix.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1532#issuecomment-559089259

Comment: I hace downgraded and the problem persist

Comment: Or just wait until version 1.3.3 gets released since it will have the fix.

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/799#issuecomment-441224399?

Comment: Yes, also added them before asking and nothing